# Are Python's output streams thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dispy

I'm using Dispy/pycos to run multiple jobs across a multitude of machines. The results of computations come back to the main script, which writes them out into a set of files -- from different threads.

Do I need to explicitly synchronize output operations in my code -- to prevent lines output by different threads from garbling each other -- or is this already taken care of for me by Python?

So far I have seen no such garbling, but, maybe, it was just luck?..

Comment: They are not thread safe, but possibly the libraries you're using handle that, I'm not familiar with dispy/pycos.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#multi-threading)